# keras pre-trained ResNet50 target shape

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I am trying to use ResNet50 Pretrained network for segmentation problem.
I remove the last layer and add my desired layer. But when I try to fit, I get the following error:

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_1 to have shape (16, 16, 1) but got array with shape (512, 512, 1)

I have two folders: images and masks. images are RGB and masks are in grayscale.
The shape is 512x512 for all images. 
I can not figure in which part am I doing wrong.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
image_input=Input(shape=(512, 512, 3))
model = ResNet50(input_tensor=image_input,weights='imagenet',include_top=False)
x = model.output
x = Conv2D(1, (1,1), padding="same", activation="sigmoid")(x)
model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=x)
model.summary()

conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 16, 16, 1)    2049 activation_49[0][0]              

for layer in model.layers[:-1]:
    layer.trainable = False

for layer in model.layers[-1:]:
    layer.trainable = True
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. If the answer was helpful in any way, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your network gives an output of shape `(16, 16, 1)` but your `y` (target) has shape `(512, 512, 1)`

Run the following to see this.

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras.layers import Input

image_input=Input(shape=(512, 512, 3))
model = ResNet50(input_tensor=image_input,weights='imagenet',include_top=False)
model.summary()

# Output shows that the ResNet50 network has output of shape (16,16,2048)

from keras.layers import Conv2D

conv2d = Conv2D(1, (1,1), padding="same", activation="sigmoid")
conv2d.compute_output_shape((None, 16, 16, 2048))

# Output shows the shape your network's output will have.
```

Either your `y` or the way you use ResNet50 has to change. Read about ResNet50 to see what you are missing.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. Here I am trying to do segmentation with UNET.  So the final layer shape should be same as input shape(512x512). When I run your comment, I have this output  (None, 16, 16, 1). What am I missing here?

Comment: The network you have created is not fit for the task you have in mind. if you need a particular shape in output (512,512,1), you have to create your network accordingly.  Resnet is a classification network. You have to follow it up with proper decoder layers to achieve the task.
<https://medium.com/nanonets/how-to-do-image-segmentation-using-deep-learning-c673cc5862ef> gives some explanation about image segmentation task. I hope this is what you are looking for. Read papers on some of the networks mentioned there to understand how to create a segmentation network.